# How do I store locations in neo4j to make geography based search better

Tags: search, neo4j, google-places-api

I have nodes like

```
    (p: Program)-[:DEPLOYED_AT]->(l : Location)
```

A program can be deployed at any location. The information which I am storing in Location node is that which I am getting from Google place autocomplete api. I have to search for programs using location. And user can search any location it can either be country, state, city or even locality. I want to know what and how the place  info should be stored in location node to make search better. Search would be like, if I am searching for "India" then it should show me all the programs deployed in "India", if I am searching for a state like "Karnataka" then it should show me only those programs which are deployed in "Karnataka" and same for city and locality. Firstly I thought I would store country, state city, lat, long in my Location node and when user search for a particular location say "Bengaluru" then I will fetch city, state and country from the searched location and give the result. But sometimes its very difficult to fetch city, state , country from searched location specially in case of locality.  I also don't want to restrict this search only for India so I have to store the location in such a way that it should support all the location search . Storing city, state, country will fail in many cases. I am curious to know how do sites like airbnb, housing store the location based information. All comments and suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would it help you if you break up the location node into locality, city, state, and country?

Comment: @manonthemat In some cases it's very difficult to fetch locality, city, state, country from a user searched location. I can fetch these things from google autocomplete object but  I also  want search location as a query parameter during filtering so its difficult for me to fetch all these thing from a query param. And I don't know whether all countries have such locality, city, state like system.